# showing "No such module 'FirebaseEmailAuthUI' " with swift package manager dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, swift-package-manager

I was trying to use Firebaseui with SPM but after installing dependency I'm not able to import these files.

```
import FirebaseEmailAuthUI
import FirebaseFacebookAuthUI
import FirebaseAnonymousAuthUI
import FirebasePhoneAuthUI
import FirebaseOAuthUI
import FirebaseGoogleAuthUI
```

how can i use this?

Comment: Did you add `pod 'FirebaseUI/Email'`to you pod file?

Comment: I'm using pods in my project. All libraries injecting through SPM

Answer (score 0):

resolved after installing below dependency.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS